# How to make text object restricted to certain height?

Tags: text-object

See the image and you understand my problem.[image]

I have followed this excellent tutorial:
[Is it possible to drive the contents of an existing text object with a text file?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39648/is-it-possible-to-drive-the-contents-of-an-existing-text-object-with-a-text-file)

I have also made my text object to be in text box with a setting of Width: 7.8 but how can I "cut" or "restrict" this dynamic text so it does not flow over the 3d phone objects screen?

Pekka Varis

Comment: Would you consider using a mask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object above text and set it's material to holdout:

[image]

Comment: @PekkaVaris Don't thank in the comments, this site works best if you upvote the answer. If it solved your problem consider making it as accepted. https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers